# Sort table with data dom graphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Im trying to sort the data i'm getting from graphQL..please look at the print screen if you see any problems.

I wanna be able to click the "Size" table head and sort the table by diameter.

The error i'm getting is **TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'**

This is my query:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const ALL_PLANETS = gql`
  query {
    allPlanets {
      planets {
        id
        name
        gravity
        diameter
        population
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And the rest:

```
function PlanetList() {
  const [sortTable, setSortTable] = useState('default');
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ALL_PLANETS);
  const history = useHistory();

  //Timeout to set variable after the fetch is done
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const planetDiameter = data.allPlanets.planets.map(
        (planet) => planet.diameter
      );
      console.log(planetDiameter);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  });

  //Conditional for loading or error
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :</p>;

  //Sort helper
  const sortTypes = {
    up: {
      class: 'sort-up',
      fn: (a, b) => a.planetDiameter - b.planetDiameter,
    },
    down: {
      class: 'sort-down',
      fn: (a, b) => b.planetDiameter - a.planetDiameter,
    },
    default: {
      class: 'sort',
      fn: (a, b) => a,
    },
  };

  //Sort function
  const onSortChange = () => {
    let nextSort;

    if (sortTable === 'down') nextSort = 'up';
    else if (sortTable === 'up') nextSort = 'default';
    else if (sortTable === 'default') nextSort = 'down';

    setSortTable(nextSort);
  };

  return (
    <div className='planets-container'>
      <table className='table-fixed'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th className='cursor-pointer' onClick={() => onSortChange()}>
              Size
              <i className={`fas fa-${sortTypes[sortTable].class}`}></i>
            </th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Gravity</th>
          </tr>
          {data.allPlanets.planets
            .sort(sortTypes[sortTable].fn)
            .map((planet) => {
              const handleRowClick = () => {
                history.push(`/planet/${planet.name}`, { params: planet.id });
              };
              return (
                <tr
                  className='border hover:bg-sky-700 border-slate-300 cursor-pointer'
                  onClick={() => handleRowClick()}
                  key={planet.id}
                >
                  <td>{planet.name}</td>
                  <td>{planet.diameter}</td>
                  <td>{planet.population}</td>
                  <td>{planet.gravity}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PlanetList;
```

See img where i'm getting the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl3Tb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1GoF.jpg

Comment: The error indicates a datatype mismatch. You are trying to use an array like an object and incorrectly adding an object property to an array, since arrays are objects in JS this sometimes works. I'm not sure exactly where the error is happening, does the error indicate a line number? Can you indicate what line the error is on?

Comment: @Philippe I've updated the post with some new code (still getting the error) but with an img that shows what line i'm getting it on.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the problem.

Needed a new array fort the sort function here.

```
{[...data.allPlanets.planets]
        .sort(sortTypes[sortTable].fn)
        .map((planet) => {
          const handleRowClick = () => {
            history.push(`/planet/${planet.name}`, { params: planet.id });
          };
          return (
            <tr
              className='border hover:bg-sky-700 border-slate-300 cursor-pointer'
              onClick={() => handleRowClick()}
              key={planet.id}
            >
              <td>{planet.name}</td>
              <td>{planet.diameter}</td>
              <td>{planet.population}</td>
              <td>{planet.gravity}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
```

Here I was trying to sort the wrong stuff.

```
      const sortTypes = {
    up: {
      class: 'sort-up',
      fn: (a, b) => a.diameter - b.diameter,
    },
    down: {
      class: 'sort-down',
      fn: (a, b) => b.diameter - a.diameter,
    },
    default: {
      class: 'sort',
      fn: (a, b) => a,
    },
  };
```

Maybe it'll help somebody.